# How do I check the average count of words in a dataset?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset that has been trained and validated, and now I want to check the total average amount of words in the dataset per tweet, based on the label. I have a dataset of tweets that contains 5 major emotion classification labels- happy, sadness, anger, fear and love. I heard count can be used to see the amount of words used in a dataset but I encountered an error:

```
temp2 = 0

for row in df_h['clean']:
    temp2 = temp2 + count(row.split())
avg_h = temp/len(df_h)

temp2 = 0
for row in df_s['clean']:
    temp2 = temp2 + count(row.split())
avg_s = temp/len(df_s)

temp2 = 0
for row in df_a['clean']:
    temp2 = temp2 + count(row.split())
avg_a = temp/len(df_a)

temp2 = 0
for row in df_f['clean']:
    temp2 = temp2 + count(row.split())
avg_f = temp/len(df_f)

temp2 = 0
for row in df_l['clean']:
    temp2 = temp2 + count(row.split())
avg_l = temp/len(df_l)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

kelas = ['happy', 'sadness', 'anger', 'fear', 'sadness']
y_pos = np.arange(len(kelas))
average = [avg_h, avg_s, avg_f, avg_a, avg_l] 

plt.bar(y_pos, average, align='center', alpha=0.5, width=0.9)

plt.xticks(y_pos, kelas)
plt.ylabel('average tweets')
plt.title('characteristic of tweets')

# for a,b in zip(y_pos, kelas):
#    plt.text(a, b, str(b), horizontalalignment='center')
    
plt.savefig('average_tweet.png')
plt.show()
```

however, I got an error that said that 'count' is not defined properly. How do I define the count so it can calculate the average amount of words per label? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use len(row.split()) instead of count(row.split()).

When you used split(), you got a list of strings. In order to find the number of these split strings, you need to simply find the length of this resulting list which you get from row.split().

Count has another function which is not exactly applicable here. count() returns the number of occurrences of a substring in the given string.